# AL INTENTAR GUARDAR EL id (pk) en telefono_id (fk) me dice que el valor de id es NULL

Tags: laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de la tabla teléfonos se guardan correctamente, la tabla paises es solo para selecionar de que pais es.
El problema se me da al intentar guardar los datos del usuario, y me dice que el `id` que se esta intentando guardar en el campo `telefono_id` es `NULL`, es decir ese id de telefonos es Null.

```php
public function store(Request $request, Telefono $telefono): RedirectResponse
{
    Telefono::create([
        'telefono' => $request->telefono,
        'pais_id' => $request->pais_id
    ]);

    Usuario::create([
        'nombre' => $request->nombre,
        'correo' => $request->correo,
        'telefono_id' => $telefono->id
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('usuario.index');
}
```

¿Sera que me podrian ayudar por favor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en ese codigo que publicas no se ve que se asigne en algun sitio lo que devuelva el Telefono::create(). Si te devuelve algo, tendras que asignarlo a $telefono. Si no devuelve nada (es un create) entonces despues de crearlo deberias buscar ese telefono y obtener su id, para pasarlo al Usuario::create()...

Comment: Coincido con lo que dice el comentario de Jakala y la respuesta de @Laura. Solo agregar que inyectar `Telefono $telefono` en `store(Request $request, Telefono $telefono)` no tiene ningún sentido, pues eso se usa para model binding, que en este caso no aplica

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el error podría ser que estás creando un nuevo objeto **Telefono** llamado **$telefono**, pero no estás asignando ningún valor a sus propiedades (por ejemplo, el ID). Luego, estás tratando de acceder al ID de este objeto en la creación del usuario, lo que seguramente dará valor nulo.

Prueba con esto:

```
public function store(Request $request, Telefono $telefono): RedirectResponse {

    $nuevoTelefono = Telefono::create([
        'telefono' => $request->telefono,
        'pais_id' => $request->pais_id
    ]);

    Usuario::create([
        'nombre' => $request->nombre,
        'correo' => $request->correo,
        'telefono_id' => $nuevoTelefono->id 
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('usuario.index');
}
```